# Image doesnt show instantly after upload with PHP

Tags: php, html, database, image

I have a system of Admins that can upload a image as profile picture. There is no error whatsoever but the image doesnt display after the upload its done, also refreshing the page doesnt work, in order to show it i have to close the admin session and log in again with the same admin. I was wondering if there is a way to refresh the session to show the image or any other solution that can solve this.

This is the php that echo html:

```
<?php
        if (isset($_SESSION["adminuid"])) {

            $name = $_SESSION["adminuid"];
            $adminType = $_SESSION["admintype"];
            $profilepic = $_SESSION["adminimg"] ?? "";
        
            switch (basename(getUrl())) {
                case "adminprofile.php":
                    echo '<div class="admin-info">
                        <h4>Bienvenido '. $name .'!</h4>';
                    echo '<div class="profile-img-container">';
                        displayImg($profilepic);
                    echo '
                            </div>
                        </div>';
                    break;
```

And these are the functions:

```
function loginUser($conn, $username, $pwd){
    $uidExists = uidExists($conn, $username, $username);

    if($uidExists === false){
        header("location: ../signin.php?error=notregistered");
        exit();
    }

    $pwdHashed = $uidExists["pwdAdmin"];
    $checkPwd = password_verify($pwd, $pwdHashed);

    if ($checkPwd === false) {
        header("location: ../signin.php?error=wrongpassword");
        exit();
    }
    else if ($checkPwd === true){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["adminid"] = $uidExists["idAdmin"];
        $_SESSION["adminuid"] = $uidExists["uidAdmin"];
        $_SESSION["admintype"] = $uidExists["typeAdmin"];
        $_SESSION["adminimg"] = $uidExists["imgAdmin"];
        header("location: ../adminprofile.php");
        exit();
    }
}

function displayImg($data){
    if ($data == "") {
        echo "<img src='img/default-profile.png'>";
    }else {
        echo "<img src='{$data}'>";
    }
}
```

As i said there are no errors inside the code, the only thing i need its a way to display the image with a refresh or restart the session without kicking the user out.

Comment: You should do `session_start()` at the very beginning of the script, to prevent problems if the script produces some unexpected output earlier. Check your PHP log for "Headers already sent" warnings and fix them.

Comment: After the upload has been submitted by the user and your script moves the file. You need to re populate this variable $_SESSION["adminimg"] with the new data. Looks like this variable only populates once at the top.